# Removing space at the beginning of the variable data

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, whitespace

I would like to ask if how can I remove the space in the beginning of the stored data of the variable.
I had an auto-generated script that will get `MySQL COUNT` from the DB.

`MYSQL COUNT SCRIPT`-> `.ini file (variable holder / parameters)` -> `report-script`

This mean that I have script that will count the some data in the database then it will data will stored in a text`(.ini)` file as variable then a another script will read the file and look for the variable.

Under the `db-count-script.sh` here some of related codes on my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql_count=$(mysql ... -e"USE my_db;SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db.sr1 WHERE intime='1';"

echo $mysql_count #This is the output of this echo --> COUNT(*) 15

#from here I'm going to remove the COUNT(*)
cnt=${mysql_count//COUNT(*)}

#storing the data to the variable
echo "db_cnt=\""$cnt"\"" >> db-count.ini
```

Inside the `db-count.ini` I have this data.

```
db_cnt=" 7"
```

I want to remove the whitespace on that variable because I have script to call this variable like this and for the future use I really need the data of the variable clean.

```
#!/bin/bash
source db-count.ini
echo "Count:"$db_cnt
#Output 
Count: 7
```

Any suggestion? Tips?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have `mysql` **not output `COUNT(*)` in the first place** with `-N` or `--skip-column-names`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trim whitespace from the front of `db_cnt` variable in bash use:

```
db_cnt="${db_cnt#"${db_cnt%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

Example:

```
$ db_cnt=" 7"
$ echo "$db_cnt"
 7
$ db_cnt="${db_cnt#"${db_cnt%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
$ echo "$db_cnt"
7
$
```

You can use the syntax to customise your script in whatever way you want.

Comment: `db_cnt` inside the `db_cnt`?
or you mean sir: `db_cnt="${cnt#"${cnt%%[![:space:]]*}"}" `

Comment: or  `cnt="${db_cnt#"${db_cnt%%[![:space:]]*}"}"`

Comment: I gave you the line to trim whitespace from a variable. You can customise your script as you want.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `echo` will remove space fromboth front and back

```
db_cnt=$(echo $db_cnt)
```

If you want to remove the whitespace just in front but want to preserve spaces at the end of variable, you can do it using `sed` as

```
db_cnt=$(echo "$db_cnt" | sed 's/^ *//')
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting a line to an array and selecting it's array position will trim spaces.

```
while read input; do
   if [[ $input =~ COUNT\(\*\) ]]; then
       hunks=($input)
       db_cnt=${hunks[1]}
       echo $db_cnt
       break;
   fi
done < input
```